# RUBY ON RAILS -Retrieve "Likes" from facebook api pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the likes from a company pages (coca-cola) I used this code but console report error "no such file and directory"

```
def facebook_likes()
 data = open("http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305").read
 data = JSON.parse(data)
 @likes = data['likes']

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
def facebook_likes
  uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305")
  data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  @likes = JSON.parse(data)['likes']
end
```